# receiving files over bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, file-sharing

On previous versions of Ubuntu I seem to recall having the option to "browse device" (like on Mac OS X) enabled by default in Bluetooth settings. Now I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I can very easily *send* files through the bluetooth settings menu, but there exists no option to *receive* files.

I have tried installing

- bluez
- blueman
- obexftp

and some other applications in the hopes of inadvertently enabling this functionality, but nothing I've done seems to have worked. I would like to find a GUI solution, as I don't want to have to fiddle around in the command line too often just to browse files on my bluetooth devices, and I need this functionality very frequently, as I use a tablet, connected to my laptop by bluetooth, to do things like signing documents and such. Does anyone know how to get this working on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Receiving files in Blueman can be enabled by right clicking on Blueman icon, go to Local Services, Transfer, enable Accept files from trusted devices and choose a folder to store them on

Comment: I'm not sure what "tray icon" is, but I found the menu you recommended under View > Local Services > Transfer in the Blueman app. Problem solved! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the bluetooth settings and connect your device (in my case an Android phone). If they have never been connected before you will have to accept a pairing message on both devices (check that the numbers are the same).
2. **Leave the Ubuntu Bluetooth dialog open** or the file will say that it has been transferred in the sending device but you will find nothing in your Downloads folder.
3. Send the file via Bluetooth to your connected Ubuntu machine.
4. Once it is done, check in the **Downloads** folder.

After you are done you can disconnect the devices and close Bluetooth settings.